# Include eps figures in class: report

Tags: graphics, eps

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graphs/power.eps}
    \caption{test}
    \label{fig:power}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I used the `linux` command `epstopdf` to convert the `eps` to `pdf`. I see the `.pdf` also in the folder

```
 305K 2013-12-13 18:48 power.eps
 65K 2013-12-13 18:48 power.pdf
```

It still shoots this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.96 \includegraphics
[scale=0.5]{graphs/power.eps}
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: You're missing `\usepackage{graphicx}`. Also use `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graphs/power}` so, depending on the engine, `.eps` or `.pdf` will be used.

Comment: We need to give the extension (from my knowledge). EDIT: I apologize it works!

Comment: On the other hand, I do not think `scale` is such a good idea, it is IMO better to scale via a desired width instead. Giving it in terms of `\textwidth` gives something that scales nicely when the margins are changed.